# Multiple repeated child elements xml

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, simple-framework

Looking for a bit of help here.

I was about to parse this xml file using simpleXml but I´m not 100% sure how to procede.

This is a snippet of the xml code:

```
<bible abbrev="ReinaV" name="Reina Valera Actualizada">
  <book num="Gen">
    <chapter num="1">
      <verse num="1">En el principio creó Dios los cielos y la tierra
      </verse>
      <verse num="2">
      Y la tierra estaba sin orden y vacía. Había tinieblas sobre la faz del
      océano, y el Espíritu de Dios se movía sobre la faz de las aguas.
      </verse>
      <verse num="3">Entonces dijo Dios: "Sea la luz", y fue la luz.</verse>
      <verse num="4">
       Dios vio que la luz era buena, y separó Dios la luz de las tinieblas.
      </verse>
    </chapter>
  </book>
</bible>
```

This is what I had so far:

```
@Root
public class bible {

@Attribute
String abbrev;
@Attribute
String name;
@Element
Book book;

public String getAbbrev() {
    return abbrev;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Book getBook() {
    return book;
}

@Root(strict = false)
private class Book {

    @Attribute(required = false)
    String num;

    @Element(required = false)
    Chapter chapter;

    private class Chapter {
    }
  }
}
```

How do i manage the repeating verse elements? thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `List` with `@ElementList`-annotation. Since `@ElementList` will create an element wrapping the list's content, use `inline = true` to prevent this.

### Bible

```
@Root(name = "bible")
public class Bible
{
    @Attribute
    private String name;
    @Attribute
    private String abbrev;
    @Element(required = false)
    private Book book;

    // ...
}
```

### Book

```
@Root(name = "book")
public class Book
{
    @Attribute
    private String num;
    @Element(required = false)
    private Chapter chapter;

    // ...
}
```

### Chapter

```
@Root(name = "chapter")
public class Chapter
{
    @Attribute
    private String num;
    @ElementList(name = "verse", required = false, inline = true) /* <-- ! */
    private List<Verse> verse;

    // ...
}
```

### Verse

```
@Root(name = "verse")
public class Verse
{
    @Attribute
    private String num;
    @Text
    private String text;

    // ...
}
```

Btw., all those `required = false` are *optional*, i have set them to enable eg. an empty book - with no child elements. If that wont make sense, just remove them.

With `@ElementList` you can have a chapter with multiple verse - but you can do the same with eg. books; a book may have multiple chapters etc..

Comment: If your problem is solved? If so, please *accept* the answer.